# Override Cell (A1) Color in sheet 1 to color blue, if phone number in A1Sheet2= phone number in A1sheet1, and A1Sheet2 is set to color blue

Tags: google-sheets, automation

I have leads data flowing in Sheet1 - AutomatedLeads (From Facebook/Instagram)
Sheet 1 A1 contains phone numbers of all leads.
Sheet 2 A2 contains phone numbers of all leads who didnot pick up when called.
When leads respond back, Sheet2 A2 is updated with color Blue manually
Sheet 1 A1 should also now be updated to color blue, automatically.
Is there a way to go about this?
Tried conditional formatting but its not working between two sheets

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional formatting but you would need a helper column for this since you can not read the color of the cell natively and use that in formulas.

You can use the following formula for `Sheet1`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:B"),2,0)
```

[image]

This is the formula and condition for `Sheet2`:

```
=(B:B=TRUE)
```

[image]

Final result:

When marking the values from `Sheet2` they also get changed in `Sheet1`.

[image]

[image]